# Inequalities in Euclidean space of dimension n

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, sobolev-spaces

While Studying Sobolev spaces, I have come across following two inequalities. For an element $\xi \in \mathbb{R^n}$and $N$,smallest integer greater than $n/2$, we have

\begin{equation}
   \bigg( 1+\sum^{n}_{j=1}|\xi_j|^{N}\bigg)^{-2} \le c|\xi|^{-n-1}
\end{equation}
 (though a terrible estimate for small values of $|\xi|$) and
\begin{equation}
    \sum^{n}_{j=1}|\xi _j|^{2N} \ge c|\xi|^{2N}
\end{equation} 
I have no clue how to go about proving these inequalities for myself. Any help will be deeply acknowledged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two main ingredients are compactness and homogeneity.

#### Compactness

**Claim**: If $f$ and $g$ are continuous real functions on a compact set $K$, and $f>0$ everywhere on $K$, then there exists a constant $c>0$ such that $f(x) \ge cg(x)$ everywhere on $K$.

*Proof*: the function $g/f$ is continuous on $K$, therefore is bounded above by some constant $C$. This yields $f\ge C^{-1}g$ as claimed. $\quad\Box$

#### Homogeneity

**Definition**: A function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is homogeneous of degree $d$ if $f(t\xi) = t^d f(\xi)$ for all $\xi\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and all $t>0$.

**Claim**: Suppose that $f$ is nonnegative and homogeneous of degree $d$, and $g$ is homogeneous of degree $d'\le d$. If there is a constant $c$ such that $f\ge cg$ on the unit sphere $S^{n-1}$, then $f(\xi)\ge cg(\xi)$ for all $|\xi|\ge 1$.

*Proof*: Given $\xi$ with $|\xi| > 1$, write it as $\xi=t\eta$ where $t=|\xi|>1$ and $|\eta|=1$. Then 
$$
f(\xi) = t^d f(\eta) \ge t^d c g(\eta) = t^{d-d'} cg(\xi) \ge cg(\xi)
$$
as claimed. $\quad\Box$

Additional remark: if $d=d'$, then having inequality $f\ge cg$ on the sphere implies having it on the entire space, since we have
$$
f(\xi) = t^d f(\eta) \ge t^d c g(\eta) = cg(\xi) 
$$
without the need for $t>1$.

---

With the above, the inequalities become obvious. For example, the first one is equivalent to 
$$
1 + \sum^{n}_{j=1}|\xi_j|^{N} \ge C|\xi|^{(n+1)/2}
\tag1$$
Considering both sides on the unit ball $|\xi|\le 1$, we see that such $C$ exists by compactness and the left hand side being positive. 
By the same reasoning, there is another $C$ such that 
$$
\sum^{n}_{j=1}|\xi_j|^{N} \ge C|\xi|^{(n+1)/2}
\tag2$$
holds on the sphere $|\xi|=1$. The left hand side of (2) is homogeneous of degree $N$, the right hand side is homogeneous of degree $(n+1)/2$. Since $N\ge (n+1)/2$, it follows that (2) holds for $|\xi|>1$ as well.

The second is simpler:
$$
    \sum^{n}_{j=1}|\xi _j|^{2N} \ge c|\xi|^{2N}
$$
holds on the unit sphere by compactness, and extends to the entire space by homogeneity (both sides are homogeneous of degree $2N$).